# Hidden column but not read the correct value

Tags: java, jtable, tablemodel

I create a simple JTable with TableModel, and I hidden the first column.
I set at my JTable also the TableRowSorter
This is the code that I use to create a table

```
tableModelArticoliVendere = new MyTableModelDescrizioneArticoli();
tableArticoliVendere = new CustomTableArticoliDaVendereBar(tableModelArticoliVendere);  
sorter = new TableRowSorter<MyTableModelDescrizioneArticoli>(tableModelArticoliVendere);
tableArticoliVendere.setRowSorter(sorter);
tableArticoliVendere.addMouseListener(new MyMouseAdapterArticoliDaVendere());
tableArticoliVendere.removeColumn(tableArticoliVendere.getColumnModel().getColumn(0));
```

If the user click on the one row of the table the mouse listenere are called.

This is the method:

```
public class MyMouseAdapterArticoliDaVendere extends MouseAdapter {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
        JTable t = (JTable)me.getSource();
        if (me.getClickCount() == 1) {
            String codiceArticolo =((JTable)tableArticoliVendere).getModel().getValueAt(t.getSelectedRow(), 0).toString();
            inserisciProdotto(codiceArticolo);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is this:
If I see the complete table and I clik on the one of the row table, I read the codiceArticolo right. If I use the row filter, and I try to click on the first row I have an error.

I have the table with 3 row for example:

```
TABLE
 column 0| column 1
 ------------------
 valore1 | 1
 valore2 | 2
 valore3 | 3
```

If I use the filter I have this situation:

```
 TABLE
 column 0| column 1
 ------------------
 valore2 | 2
 valore3 | 3
```

if I try to click on the first row, the value of codiceArticolo is valore1 and not valore2.

If I not hidden the column 0, I don't have this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have sorting or filtering enabled in your table, the indexes of *table* rows and columns stop lining up with indexes of the *model* rows and columns. You can account for this using [`convertRowIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29) and [`convertColumnIndexToModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertColumnIndexToModel%28int%29).

For instance, when you use `t.getSelectedRow()`, you can adjust like this:

```
int tableRowIndex = t.getSelectedRow();
int modelRowIndex = t.convertRowIndexToModel(tableRowIndex);
```

It will also help if you indicate in your code when you are using view indexes and when you are using model indexes.